# How can I predict values in factorial experiments (2^k) with centre points in R?

Tags: r, regression, prediction

How can I predict values in factorial experiments with centre points in R using `FrF2` package with the `predict` function or using the `broom` package?

My code:

```
library(FrF2)
plan.person = FrF2(nfactors = 5, resolution = 5, replications = 2,
               ncenter = 1, randomize = FALSE,
               factor.names = list(
                 A = c(8, 5),
                 B = c(70, 30),
                 C = c(0.5, 0),
                 D = c(1000, 700),
                 E = c(70, 10)))

resp  <- c(84.55, 66.34, -1, 69.18, 73.01, 64.52, 0.73, 47.61, 68.18, 59.87, 
       26, 72.57, 78.08, 73.81, 26, 59.38, 71.41, 88.64, 64.92, 4, 68.81, 
       80, 69.66, -1.36, 54.50, 79.24, 78.53, -1, 72.63, 89.97, 87.98, 
       -11, 65.68, 82.46)

newplan <- add.response(design = plan.person, response = resp)

model <- lm(newplan, use.center = T)
# summary(model)

d <- within(newplan, {
  A <- as.numeric(as.character(A))
  B <- as.numeric(as.character(B))
  C <- as.numeric(as.character(C))
  D <- as.numeric(as.character(D))
  E <- as.numeric(as.character(E)) })

A = seq(5, 8, 1)
B = seq(30, 70, length.out = length(A))
C = seq(0, 0.5, length.out = length(A))
D = seq(700, 1000, length.out = length(A))
E = seq(10, 70, length.out = length(A))

data <- expand.grid(A = A, B = B,
                C = C, D = D,
                E = E)  

dados$p <- predict(model, newdata=data)
```

Because of the center point the following message appears.

> Error in model.frame.default (Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object $ xlevels):
>      lengths of variables differ (found in 'center')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the central value, you can this after `model <- lm(newplan, use.center = T)`
:

1- Filter the pvalues < 0.05

```
coe <- broom::tidy(model) %>% 
  slice(-7) %>%   #remove center
  filter(p.value < 0.05)   

m_beta <- coe$estimate
```

2 - Do a grid:

```
A = seq(5, 8, 0.5)
B = seq(30, 70, length.out = length(A))

exp <- expand.grid(A = A, B = B) %>% 
  mutate(bo = as.numeric(1)) %>% 
  mutate(ult = A*B) %>% 
  select(bo, A, B, ult) %>% 
  as.matrix()
```

3: Do a Regression:

```
reg <- t(m_beta %*% t(exp)) 

exp <- cbind(exp, reg) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rename(reg = V5)
```

But I believe this only solves the computational problem or simplifies it. I believe linear regression should be redone as well. But with this code you can explore and see what other errors exist.

Comment: Filtering by p-value and then using the result for prediction is wrong. If you really want to do model selection, the model needs to be refit.

Comment: @bbiasi: Your question was "how do predict values with center points..." This answer starts "if you remove the center points..." Are you sure it answers your question?

Comment: @Aaron It seems to me correct the manipulation, because with the estimation of the coefficients it is possible to generate the regression model. And with this manipulation of data it is possible to do this. The central point of information does not enter the equation of my model, right?

Comment: Well, yes and no. When you write out the model as fit, you only add the center point value when you're at the center point, If you use that to get fitted values at other points, that results in a (twisted) plane with a point bump at the center. But you almost certainly believe that the fitted values should smoothly interpolate between the fits at the 2^k values and the center point, so yes, that center point should affect the equation of your model at non-center points too. However, with only a 2^k + center point, there are multiple ways to do that interpolation...

Comment: ... and so you need a fuller response surface design to fit that surface.

Comment: Ok, but my equation model will be different in that? Note that the equation of the model considers the centre point, it just set up the regression model by removing the information from the central point and filtering the significant betas.

Answer (score 3):

"A two-level experiment with center points can detect, but not fit, quadratic effects."
(https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section3/pri336.htm)

That is, R can't predict these values because you need to make additional assumptions about what the curve looks like to predict points not at your design points.

Note that computationally, you can get the software to work by adding a `center` term. The error is because this term is in the regression but not in the data set. You could add one with `data$center <- FALSE` (because none of the points in `data` are at the center), but this will *not* do the right thing, as it will not take the potential curvature into account when predicting non-central points, it would simply predict a twisted plane (that is, linear with interactions) with a single bump at the center.

Of course, it's also equivalent to just fitting the model with `use.center=FALSE`, as the center point doesn't affect the fit of the other points.